# How to return select phrases from Nokogiri

Tags: html, ruby, web-scraping, command-line-interface, nokogiri

I'm trying to parse through a string output from the HTML of a [site](https://openoversight.lucyparsonslabs.com/department/1) I'm scraping.

I'm using:

```
 officer.race = doc.css("dd").map {|r| r.text.strip}
```

But this outputs every attribute of the officers on the first page:

```
Rank POLICE OFFICER Race White Hispanic Gender F Number of Photos 0 Rank POLICE OFFICER Race White Gender M Number of Photos 0
```

and so on.

I just need the race of all 20 officers on the first page to feed to my Officer class' race attribute accessor. The HTML of the site doesn't really give me a way to specify further to my knowledge.

Is there a way to do this? Or am I looking at the issue wrong?

Comment: Welcome to SO. When asking, it's important to reduce the HTML to the smallest possible chunk demonstrates the problem, and include that in your question. Asking us to retrieve and trawl through a page to find the part you're discussing wastes our time, _and_ if your link to the page breaks, the question will make no sense. Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and all their linked pages
 and then improve your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd start with:

```rb
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(URI.open('https://openoversight.lucyparsonslabs.com/department/1'))
doc.search("div.col-md-6.col-xs-6 dt:contains('Race')+dd").map(&:text)
# => ["White Hispanic",
#     "White",
#     "White",
#     "White",
#     "White",
#     "Asian/pacific Islander",
#     "Asian/pacific Islander",
#     "White",
#     "Asian/pacific Islander",
#     "Black",
#     "Black",
#     "White",
#     "White",
#     "Asian/pacific Islander",
#     "White",
#     "White",
#     "White Hispanic",
#     "White Hispanic",
#     "White Hispanic",
#     "White Hispanic"]
```

`div.col-md-6.col-xs-6` is the first part of the magic. That particular div and class contains the fields you want, so just grab them throughout the page as it's the innermost distinct tag.

Nokogiri contains extensions to add jQuery's CSS extensions, allowing us to use CSS more like XPath. XPath is still more powerful, but it's also visually painful at times so I use CSS predominately. The Nokogiri documentation recommends CSS for the same sort of reason.

`dt:contains('Race')+dd` then causes Nokogiri to find the `dt` tags containing "Race", and `+` tells it to grab the next `dd` tag, which contains the actual text.

---

Of course, you're probably going to want to do a little counting:

```
doc.search("div.col-md-6.col-xs-6 dt:contains('Race')+dd").map(&:text).tally
# => {"White Hispanic"=>5, "White"=>9, "Asian/pacific Islander"=>4, "Black"=>2}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your selector isn't specific enough so it's picking up every `dd`.

```
.list-group-item > div.row > div:last-child > .row > div:first-child > dl > dd:last-child
```

You're looking to traverse through `.list-group-item`, then to `.row`, then to the last `div` inside that element, then the child `.row`, then the first `div`, then the `dl`, then the last `dd`

Comment: You explained it really well and it works! I had a feeling it wasn't specific enough but didn't know how to go about it, thank you!

Comment: No, no, no. Using a long chain of selectors is more likely to break if the page's layout changes. Instead, find specific way-points, and point to those. See my answer. Also, this selector looks like it was copied using a browser's CSS path to the element. Never trust the browser as JavaScript can move nodes after the page has been loaded, prior to it being rendered, which will result in Nokogiri not being able to find what is being selected. Always look at the raw source instead.